# list extending in python

Tags: python, list

i have just confronted this situation which i am not able to understand:

```
In [3]: nk1=range(10)

In [4]: nk2=range(11,15)

In [5]: nk1.extend(nk2)

In [6]: nk1
Out[6]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]

In [7]: dir(range(10))==dir(list)==dir(range(11,15))==dir(nk1)==dir(nk2)
Out[7]: True

In [8]: print range(10).extend(range(11,15))
None
```

as you can see above that i can easily extend nk1, but why not the last statement which is returning `None`?? 
why it is returning `None` in `In[8]` input (while from `In[7]` we can see that all are same)??? 
 so do i always have to make instance of `range` to extend it???

 from python docs; i found [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types); but i am not getting how does above case happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you extend a list the list is modified in-place. A new list is not returned.

In-place modifications indicate that the object whose method you're calling is going to make changes to itself during that method execution.  In most cases (to avoid the confusion you're currently encountering) these types of operations do not return the object that performed the operation (though there are exceptions).  Consider the following:

```
list1 = range(10)
list2 = range(10) + range(11,15) # no in place modification here.
nolist1 = list1.extend(range(11,15)) # list1 is now (0 ... 14)
nolist2 = range(10).extend(range(11,15)) # Nothing actually happens here.
```

In the final example, the `range` function returns a list which is never assigned to anything.  That list is then extended, the result of which is a return value of `None`.  This is printed.

Comment: `id(nk1)` is present, also `id(range(10)` is also present.all of them got place. so exactly what is does `IN-PLACE` means???

Comment: Means, the input argument is modified, instead of returning a modified list.

Comment: @ATOzTOA so `IN-PLACE` means without changing its `id` we are changing its content??????

Comment: `range()` will have an id, but as it dynamically creates a list, the id is not stored anywhere unless you say `x = range();`. When we do extend, the value changes for the output of range() keeping the id. Also see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`range()` gives out a handle to the newly created list. If you need to modify it, you have to store the handle to a variable.

It is not printing 'None' because `extend` doesn't return anything. As you are using range(), there is no way to get the output directly.

```
nk1 = range(10)
nk1.extend(range(11,15))
print nk1
```